# Possible to dynamically customize locale in Java?

Tags: java, internationalization, locale

I have a situation in which a client for obscure reasons wants a specific locale to be in place, *except* for the modification that month names in lower case as per the locale should be shown in upper case (which is not a standard variant of the locale in question). I already have `SimpleDateFormatter` code in place referencing an instance of `Locale`.

My question is whether it is possibly to dynamically construct an instance of Locale based on a designated country code, *but with specifically given modifications?* Or, alternatively, whether it is possible to build a locale instance from scratch, specifying all details at runtime, such that a `SimpleDateFormatter` referencing it would change its casing of months accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `new Locale("myLang", "myCountry", "myVariant")` not do what you want?

Comment: @rodion How would that go beyond selecting preexisting locales?

Comment: As far as I could interpret the question, you want to dynamically construct a `Locale` from scratch, specifying details at runtime. So why can you not construct a new locale with `new Locale(myDynamicLang, myDynamicCountry)` for instance? Is that not dynamic enough? Is there some other specific functionality you are looking for?

Comment: @rodion Thanks for your feedback - seems I failed to be precise enough, though. The details I want to specify are beyond designating a particular existing culture/language, but details such as supplying an own date formatting strategy that the locale would apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc for [LocaleServiceProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html) should get you started.

Comment: I don't want to select an existing locale, however, but to construct a *new* locale with specific rules for date formatting.

Comment: The javadoc I pointed at referenced LocaleServiceProvider. I guess I could have linked directly to LocaleServiceProvider, so I did that now.